# Django Staticfiles não encontrado css não carrega

Tags: python, django

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação django, está tudo rodando perfeitamente, mas o arquivo estático não está sendo renderizado no no meu templete.

Fiz as configurações no 'settings' mas mesmo assim não funciona. abaixo está como coloquei o as configurações no settings como puxei o arquivo estático no templete.

**Configurações no settings:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'static',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

**Como estou puxando no template:**

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

**Esse é o erro que o terminal retorna:**

```
[07/Jan/2021 20:07:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 576
[WinError 3] O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado: 'C:\\Users\\rodri\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\PYTHON\\DJANGO\\projeto_final\\clientes_admin\\staticfiles/style.css'
[07/Jan/2021 20:07:37] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rodrigo, escreva o caminho completo pra pasta que contém o arquivo estático:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    "/home/projeto/app/static",

]
```

e verifica também se nos **INSTALLED_APPS** está mencionado **'django.contrib.staticfiles',**

Answer (score 0):

No settings.py  tente usar essas configurações:

Primeiro Passo:

```
DEBUG = True # caso estiver False  o projeto esta em modo de produção 

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [] # caso esteja False adicione na lista ["*"]
```

caso essas indicações estiverem Okay!

Segundo passo:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'seuApp,  #adicione a tua aplicação, não o nome do projeto.
```

Caso estiver tudo certo prossiga :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],# defina essa orientação ao templates.
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Se estiver certo passe para próxima indicação:

No final, Quando é criado um projeto  na ultima linha fica assim:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' #usado durante o desenvolvimento.
#adicione 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

dentro do app crie a pasta : static, dentro desta pasta ponha os css e htmls

no html

```
{% load static %}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

a variavel DEBUG  como False o Django não ira carregar arquivos html e css para ele carregar em modo de produção tera que usar api.